# php echo name and file paths from database to display videos with href

Tags: php, mysql, video

My knowledge of php is very limited, although I am aware that mysql functions are depreciated but it doesn't matter for the purpose of this project.

I have a table (enisatquestion) with training questions, and file paths to 14 videos stored on my pc which I want to display using localhost.

My table structure and an example of one of the rows in my table are as follows:

Columns are:

eNISATID (Auto-increment)
eNISATQuestion (Training question)
eNISATVideo  (File path to video)

An example of a Row:
1
Can you login?
http://localhost\Tna\eNISAT\LoginTutorial.wmv

Here is my code, I am getting an error;

mysql_fetch_assoc() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\Tna\eNISATVids.php on line 20

Can anyone please help me with this, I have researched a lot of ways to display this, but I am struggling with it as I have never worked with videos in php before. The videos are also wmv format. Or can anyone give me a more suitable example

Many Thanks

```
    <?php  
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
//maintain SESSION user_id

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);



//Select video name and question

$query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

$enisatquestion = "<table >";

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {


    $enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td></tr>";

}

$enisatquestion .= "</table>";    

echo $enisatquestion;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: `$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)` is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple:

```
$query = "SELECT eNISATName, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$enisatquestion = "<table>";

while ( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    $enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$r['eNISATVideo']}'>{$r['eNISATName']}</a></td></tr>";

}

$enisatquestion .= "</table>";    

echo $enisatquestion;

?>
```

Notice the new $result variable that is passed to mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Thanks David Maes, I have made the change you suggested but still getting the same error

Comment: Apologies I am receiving a different error now. Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Tna\eNISATVids.php on line 22

Comment: For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

Comment: With other words you got an error, try echo mysql_error(), and tell me what it says.

Comment: Got it working thank you David. I had a typo. One more query if you dont mind, how do I display the results in a table in this format with the href's? Thank You

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. But you can put echo "<table>"; above the while, and put echo "</table>"; beneath it. and put the <a> tags in <tr> and <td> tags, if you get what i mean. I've updated the answer, but I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks David that works. Although it is conflicting with my page header and is appearing above it. How can i position the table in the center and down the page a bit more

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen enough code of you to answer that question. But you can always look up some CSS tricks :).

Comment: Hi David, I have updated my question and added the full code I have on my page. The CSS i have provides a header on each page, with the users name and a logout function. Although on page the links displayed start at the very top of the screen, which is pushing the header below the echo. I have tried moving the code at the bottom but this conflicts with the $userrow variable. Really appreciate your help